# Git GUI crashes every time it opens a repository

Tags: git, dll, msysgit

Since few days ago, every time I start Git GUI in a repository, it displays this horrifying error message and quits after I click OK:

```
prepare-commit-msg hook failed:

      0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x68560000, RegionSize 0x260000, State 0x10000
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0

You must correct the above errors before committing.
```

It only happens with Git GUI and only when in repository (old or newly created one).  Common commands in Git Bash including commit work fine.

Un-installing and re-installing with newer package (only minor version change) did not remove the issue.  It still happens with old repositories as well as with newly created ones.

On a clean machine this issue does not reproduce, so I guess it's something on my box, but I don't remember installing anything funny.  I do remember turning off my box after a long time though, so maybe some Windows Update could have triggered this--that would also explain why the other machine does not suffer--it's 2-3 months since last Win update there.

Any ideas how to shed light into this? (As I can only see it on single machine, I don't feel like submitting it to official tracker before I know it's not my/other app's fault...)

---

**Update** after first comments:

- > If you remove or rename the hook script, does it work?

  Funny enough, but the hook script actually does not exist at all (no hook scripts are
  present--there are only *.sample files in .git\hooks).  Not even elsewhere (git program
  dir, etc.)
- > Trace it so you know what commands it ran - from git-bash run `git gui --trace`

  Sadly this does not output anything to the shell.  Behaviour is the same.
- > Maybe get gdb in there.

  I tried but gdb did not output anything useful.  However, I don't have any experience
   with GDB, I'm probably doing it wrong.  I got a [MinGW's gdb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/), ran it from command
   prompt with git.exe as argument and then ran `run gui`. gdb did not output anything
   interesting:

  ```
  (gdb) run gui
  Starting program: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe gu
  [New Thread 8264.0x1ce4]
  [New Thread 8264.0x394]
  [Inferior 1 (process 8264) exited with code 01]
  (gdb)
  ```

  But I'm almost sure I'm Doing It Wrong, so advice is more than welcome :)
- > Make sure you don't have cygwin installed or at least that it is not present in your
  >   PATH at all

  I do have cygwin installed (as I always had, before git broke).  From Cygwin I only
  have in path some *.bat launchers and some *.dll files, but I have checked with
  ProcMon that it does not touch them and even if I remove them from the path I still get
  the same crash.

Comment: If you remove or rename the hook script, does it work? `.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg`

Comment: Trace it so you know what commands it ran - from git-bash run `git gui --trace`. When it runs the prepare-commit-hook it will emit the command that it runs and you can look at that command for further debug info. Maybe get gdb in there. The fact that it complains about cygwin's heap is suspicious. Make sure you don't have cygwin installed or at least that it is not present in your PATH at all. cygwin and msys do not mix.

Comment: @patthoyts, fork0 Thanks for pointers, updated Q with replies

Comment: I see a similar issue with https://msysgit.googlecode.com/files/Git-1.8.3-preview20130601.exe now -- https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/123 . But I have no more helpful information about this.

Comment: BTW, which version of Git for Windows were you using when this error happened?

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev I can't believe I forgot to add version to the Q and got away with that. ;)  Unfortunately I can't check back, I'm already working at a different company. I'd wildly guess it was something that was available as stable at the time at the googlecode page (not sure if 1.8*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After another Windows Update and OS restart, the problem disappeared.

It seems like one of update introduced a bug which was fixed in another one.  Or it could
be a "phase-of-the-moon" bug.

I guess we'll never know...

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me.

> http://www.trinitycore.org/f/topic/5194-msysgit-couldnt-reserve-space-for-cygwins-heap/
>
> Solution:
>
> Change the base address of the msysgit.dll
>
> `c:\msysgit\bin>rebase.exe -b 0x50000000 msys-1.0.dll`

Comment: I have no idea what rebase has to do with dll (feels like dll itself is under source control if needs rebasing) but I don't care. It works :)

Comment: Works for broken GitHub Desktop client on Windows 10

Comment: @PawelCioch this is a different kind of rebase, unrelated to git, which changes the base address in memory that a DLL is loaded at.

Answer (score 9):

I've had this problem as well

I've solved it with

http://support.code-red-tech.com/CodeRedWiki/VirtualAllocPointerNull

Apparently this is caused by some feature, and replacing the dll fixes it for most people

in case the website is down -

---

**Virtual Alloc pointer is null**

Very rarely, running make may result in an error similar to this:

```
0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x71110000, RegionSize 0x350000, State 0x10000
\msys\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
```

This is a problem that affects a tiny minority of customers, and depends on what other applications they are running at the same time.

This is caused by a feature in the MSYS binaries that we use to provide the the build environment for the product.

If this happens, you can replace the file
\msys\bin\msys-1.0.dll
with the file in the attached zipfile. [msys-1.0.zip](http://support.code-red-tech.com/CodeRedWiki/VirtualAllocPointerNull?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=msys-1.0.zip)

Note that this does not fix the problem, rather it moves DLL base address.
Unfortunately, it is possible the error may occur with this replacement DLL too, again depending on what other applications are running.

---

Comment: maybe a clue to the actual problem, closing and reopening the cli made this problem go away for me. It only occurred after working correctly for a long time. In my case I had two remotes with different number of commits ahead. Will replace the dll if it happens again. Thanks

Comment: Did not work for a broken GitHub desktop client: https://gyazo.com/a402712617d4295f3385d5c083745a5e

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this too, and it was because MacType was interfering with bash.exe and msys1.0.dll.  (MacType is a font smoothing program for Windows that tries to emulate OS-X style font rasterization.) Enabling MacType only on the programs I need it, and not on the Console2 window that was trying to load bash.exe fixed the problem.

Maybe that will help someone else fix the error.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The solution which worked for me was almost same as the one suggested by XandrGuard

```
c:\msysgit\bin>rebase.exe -b 0x50000000 msys-1.0.dll
```

Solution is explained here http://jakob.engbloms.se/archives/1403

For me solution was slightly different. It was

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin>rebase.exe -b 0x50000000 msys-1.0.dll
```

Hope it helps people who are trying to google the problem

Comment: This solution worked best for me, since it directly points to the Git GUI application

Comment: That worked, though the first attempt failed:
    `ReBaseImage (msys-1.0.dll) failed with last error = 2`

Re-running it from a command prompt as administrator did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this same issue after installing 1.8.0 on a Win64 machine. I solved the issue by removing 1.8.0 and installing 1.7.11

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP didn't specifiy the version, so we can't compare his report to your case.

Answer (score 1):

Simply make a search for all `msys-1.0.dll` on your `C:\` drive, and make the one used by Git comes first.

In my case, I simply changed the order of:

```
C:\prgs\Gow\Gow-0.7.0\bin\msys-1.0.dll
C:\prgs\git\PortableGit-1.8.5.2-preview20131230\bin\msys-1.0.dll
```

By making the Git path `C:\prgs\git\PortableGit-1.8.5.2-preview20131230\bin\` come first in my `%PATH%`, the error message disappeared!

No need to reboot or to even change the DOS session.
Once the `%PATH%` is updated in that DOS session, the git commands just work.

---

Sidenote, regarding gdb:

With Git 2.25.2 (March 2020) adds a better gdb debugging experience.

See [commit 08809c0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/08809c09aa1351b603e9c55734105cd2e3c24c41) (13 Feb 2020) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e154451](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e154451a2feb7aa8c265aa7b9b0a67c7676e12c6), 17 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`mingw`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/08809c09aa1351b603e9c55734105cd2e3c24c41): add a helper function to attach GDB to the current process
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>
> When debugging Git, the criss-cross spawning of processes can make things quite a bit difficult, especially when a Unix shell script is thrown in the mix that calls a `git.exe` that then segfaults.
>
> To help debugging such things, we introduce the `open_in_gdb()` function which can be called at a code location where the segfault happens (or as close as one can get); This will open a new MinTTY window with a GDB that already attached to the current process.
>
> Inspired by Derrick Stolee.

Then [new function `open_in_gdb()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/08809c09aa1351b603e9c55734105cd2e3c24c41/compat/mingw.h#L594-L602) has the comment:

```
/*
 * For debugging: if a problem occurs, say, in a Git process that is spawned
 * from another Git process which in turn is spawned from yet another Git
 * process, it can be quite daunting to figure out what is going on.
 *
 * Call this function to open a new MinTTY (this assumes you are in Git for
 * Windows' SDK) with a GDB that attaches to the current process right away.
 */
```